# My app does not upload data to firebase when running on a real device

Tags: android

The app works fine in emulator but does not upload data to Firebase when running on a device though it gives me no error or exception could you please help me out on this problem?

Comment: Please paste logs.

Comment: Please paste relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Add your device **SHA1** key under your Firebase

**project settings -> General -> Your apps** tab.